# Joi validation schema - two fields must not have the same value

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

Assume I have the following schema:

```
var schema = {
  fieldOne: Joi.string().required(),
  fieldTwo: Joi.string().required()
};
```

Is it possible to set a validation rule that checks if both fields have different values?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes it is.  You do this by making use of [`Joi.ref`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options) and [`Joi.invalid`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyinvalidvalue---aliases-disallow-not) (aliased to `Joi.disallow`).  For your particular example, it would be:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var Joi = require('joi');

var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  fieldOne: Joi.string().required(),
  fieldTwo: Joi.string().disallow(Joi.ref('fieldOne')).required()
});
```

And testing it yields us what we would expect:

```
assert.ok(Joi.validate(4, schema).error !== null);
assert.ok(Joi.validate({ fieldOne: 'a', fieldTwo: 'a' }, schema).error !== null);
assert.ok(Joi.validate({ fieldOne: 'a', fieldTwo: 'b' }, schema).error === null);
```

It works by referencing `fieldOne` in our definition of `fieldTwo` and disallowing the same value.

Comment: Thank you Ford. Bounty will be awarded in 5 hours.

Comment: Could you please also tell me how can I do this with arrays?

Comment: Hm, never done it with arrays before.  My first thought was `Joi.array().items(Joi.string().disallow(Joi.ref('fieldOne')).required())`, doesn't seem to work though, but might be a good starting point.  If anything, it may point to a bug you could bring up on the [project page](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues).

Comment: Thank you for this! Although it's been a while, just wondering if you know of a way to do this so that the error message indicates a violation of a uniqueness constraint. With the method you posted here, the error message is something like "fieldTwo contains an invalid value", which is not 100% accurate in this case.